# Google Maps v3 panTo Callback?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

How can I set a callback function on a single specified `panTo` call? Here is my code.

```
var loc = data.split(',');
map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(loc[0], loc[1]), function(){
    console.log('this never logs...');
});
```

Answer (score 23):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.  Are you hoping the callback will run when the panning finishes?  If so, you can try this:

```
map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(loc[0], loc[1]));
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
    console.log('this logs after the panTo finishes.');
});
```

Comment: Well, I guess utilizing idle event is the best way to simulate such callback. Your solution works fine with just one exception - the idle event isn't triggered if the map center position isn't changed. The listener then remains in the app until the idle event is actually triggered (after zooming or another panning). In the end it might happen that several such listeners would be waiting for the idle event. Therefore it's necessary to check that the map center is actually being changed.